# Django Annotate Changes Query Values/Order

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to pull the 8 most recent items from my model and attach their minimum price. When I annotate the 8 most recent items, the items change unless I use order_by(). Is this a bug, or does this make my query more efficient somehow? I'm trying to better understand my queries so that I can make them faster.

```
class Item(ClusterableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-pk',)

class StoreInventory(ClusterableModel):
    item = ParentalKey('Item', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
```

Undesired

```
newest_items = Item.objects.all()[:8]

> Queryset [Item: Item object(100), ..., Item: Item object(93)]

newest_items = newest_items.annotate(price = Min('storeinventory__price'))

> Queryset [Item: Item object(1), ..., Item: Item object(8)]
```

Desired

```
newest_items = Item.objects.all().order_by('-pk')[:8]

> Queryset [Item: Item object(100), ..., Item: Item object(93)]

newest_items = newest_items.annotate(price = Min('storeinventory__price'))

> Queryset [Item: Item object(100), ..., Item: Item object(93)]
```

Comment: My guess is that you are relying on an implicit ordering which is, in fact, undefined. You've already found how to fix it. Make the ordering explicit.